# Getting percentage of Inactive users via Firebase analytics

Tags: google-analytics, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm working on Firebase analytics for my app so the following question is in the same context - Does firebase have a concept of "retained user, who did not open the app but had app on device" ? If so, does it appear on the Firebase Dashboard?

Also how can I get a count of freshly installed users (new users) for each day.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to track this on Firebase Analytics. When your users use your app, Firebase SDK sends events to FA and they aggregate this data in order to generate reports.

This way they can extract active users, but there is no way to determine users who have the app installed but they don't use it.

You can determine new users based on "first_open" event. This event shows you how many users open the app for the first time

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to compute **N-day inactive users** in BigQuery after linking-up Firebase with BQ ([Source](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9037342?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512)):

```
-- N-Day Inactive Users = users in the last M days who have not logged a user_engagement event in the last N days where M > N.

SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT M_days.user_id)
FROM (
  SELECT
    user_id
  FROM
    /* PLEASE REPLACE WITH YOUR TABLE NAME */
    `YOUR_TABLE.events_*`
  WHERE
    event_name = 'user_engagement'
    /* Has engaged in last M = 7 days */
    AND event_timestamp > UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 7 DAY))
    /* PLEASE REPLACE WITH YOUR DESIRED DATE RANGE */
    AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180521' AND '20240131') AS M_days
/* EXCEPT ALL is not yet implemented in BigQuery. Use LEFT JOIN in the interim.*/
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    user_id
  FROM
    /* PLEASE REPLACE WITH YOUR TABLE NAME */
    `YOUR_TABLE.events_*`
  WHERE
    event_name = 'user_engagement'
    /* Has engaged in last N = 2 days */
    AND event_timestamp > UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 2 DAY))
    /* PLEASE REPLACE WITH YOUR DESIRED DATE RANGE */
    AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180521' AND '20240131') AS N_days
ON
  M_days.user_id = N_days.user_id
WHERE
  N_days.user_id IS NULL
```